# convergence of a series in the space of bounded linear operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I need help in showing that:

If $X$ is a Banach space and $T \in L(X,X)$ have $||T||<1$. Use the completeness of $L(X,X)$ to show that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}T^n$ converges in $L(X,X)$. where $L(X,X)$
is the space of bounded linear operators.

thanx in advance.

Comment: @ masw980:  taking $T = I$, the identity map, we have $\Vert T \Vert = \Vert I \Vert = 1$, buy no way $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty I^n$ converges!  Perhaps you meant $\Vert T \Vert < 1$?

Comment: I just edited the problem, thanx.

Answer (score 4):

For any non-negative integer $m$ let

$S_m = \sum_{n = 0}^m T^n; \tag{1}$

we will show that the sequence $S_m$ is Cauchy.  Let $k > l$ be non-negative integers.  Then

$S_k - S_l = \sum_{n = l + 1}^k T^n = T^{l + 1} \sum_{n = 0}^{k -  l - 1} T^n = T^{l + 1}S_{k - l -1}; \tag{2}$

thus

$\Vert S_k - S_l \Vert = \Vert T^{l + 1}S_{k - l -1} \Vert \le \Vert T^{l + 1} \Vert \Vert S_{k - l -1} \Vert \le \Vert T \Vert^{l + 1} \Vert S_{k - l -1} \Vert. \tag{3}$

Consider $\Vert S_{k - l -1} \Vert$; we have

$\Vert S_{k - l -1} \Vert = \Vert \sum_{n = 0}^{k -  l - 1} T^n \Vert \le \sum_{n = 0}^{k -  l - 1} \Vert T^n \Vert \le \sum_{n = 0}^{k -  l - 1} \Vert T \Vert^n$
$\le \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \Vert T \Vert^n = \dfrac{1}{1 - \Vert T \Vert}, \tag{4}$

where we know everything converges since $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \Vert T \Vert^n$ is a real geometric series with ratio $\Vert T \Vert < 1$; it is well known that the sum of such a series is $(1 - \Vert T \Vert)^{-1}$.  Using (4) in (3) we find

$\Vert S_k - S_l \Vert \le \dfrac{\Vert T \Vert^{l + 1}}{(1 - \Vert T \Vert)}; \tag{5}$

again recalling that $\Vert T \Vert < 1$, we see that it follows from (5) that $\Vert S_k - S_l \Vert$ may be made arbitrarily small by taking $l$ sufficiently large, independently of $k$.  Thus $S_m$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L(X, X)$; as such, since $L(X, X)$ is complete, the limit $S = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty T^n \in L(X, X)$; the infinite series converges to $S$ in $L(X, X)$.  ***QED.***

***Nota Bene:***  It is worth observing, as is hinted in the above, that

$(I - T)^{-1} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty T^n; \tag{6}$

this may be seen as follows:

$(I - T)\sum_{n = 0}^m T^n = I - T^{m + 1} \tag{7}$

by simple algebra; now if we let $m \to \infty$ the right-hand side approaches $I$, since $T^{m + 1} \to 0$ by virtue of $\Vert T \Vert < 1$ ($\Vert T^{m + 1} \Vert \le \Vert T \Vert^{m + 1}$).  This is a well-known and exceedingly useful identity in the theory of linear operators.  ***End of Note.***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***